# How to ensure that hostname will be set to Virtualbox VM name when using a preseed automated install debian file with PXE boot?

Tags: debian, virtualbox, hostname, preseed

Let's say I create a VM in Virtual Box.
My environnement with TFTP boot is ready. The install goes well, except that the machine doesn't have the VM name as hostname ...

How to force that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper V has data exchange guest integration that allows virtual machines to get the host name and guest name. I am not aware of anything similar for VirtualBox, so you may be stuck with getting the name and MAC address from the VM host and remotely changing the guest name with a script or something.